# How to pass Array values to asp.net c# web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

In my client project(asp.net MVC4) I have a class file

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
}
```

And from the controller I try to call my web service method. The web service part is different project.

```
Person per = new Person();
per.Name = "Vibin";
per.Phone = 123456789;
FirstService.WebService service = new FirstService.WebService();

service.TakeList(per);
```

And my web service method is

```
[WebMethod]
public void TakeList(Person theList)
{
    // stuff
}
```

The problem is I am unable to pass the value to the web method. I searched a lot to find a solution but failed. Please help me to fix this issue. Also please provide an example for sending array values to web service in asp.net c#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, "unable?"

Comment: It shows the error "The best overloaded method match for 'mvcEmpty.FirstService.WebService.TakeList(mvcEmpty.FirstService.Person)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Your Person class needs to be defined ONCE in the web service interface and you reference that, not a different Person class in your client.  You need to remove that.

Comment: What's this got to do with arrays? I can only see one person?

Comment: @Liath I want to pass array values to the web service method. So I asked an example. I couldn't find a proper solution to that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know but it is issue of type ambiguity.

You person class that you have used is not same as Web Service defined even though both has same property.

When you add web reference it will create its own entity and you have to map your MVC model to Web service model.

```
Person per = new Person(); // your MVC4 App local model.
per.Name = "Vibin";
per.Phone = 123456789;
FirstService.WebService service = new FirstService.WebService();
mvcEmpty.FirstService.Person p = new mvcEmpty.FirstService.Person(); // Web service person generated during proxy generation when you add web reference.
p.Name = per.Name;
p.phone = per.Phone;
service.TakeList(p);
```

Comment: I tried the solution and it worked. My web service method will also be called from android project. Will it work on android project also?

Comment: If you are able to generate proxy class in Java then it works there as well. If you don't want to generate proxy class then you have to do it via web request.

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass an array to a web service method?

Comment: Do you have any such method then please provide signature.

Comment: can we chat? help me pls

Comment: Such as like 
Public class Invoice
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public int Age {get; set;}

 public string[] desc {get; set;}
 public int[] items {get; set; }
}
Invoice pe = new Invoice();
 
 pe.Name = "hubino";
        pe.Age = 21;
            
        pe.desc[0] = "Hundreds";
        pe.desc[1] = "chumma";
        pe.items[0] = 123;
        pe.items[1] = 45;
        pe.items[2] = 98;
How to pass the 'pe' variable to my web service method.

Comment: It is normal object. You don't have to worry about that. Just make sure you are using proper namespace of your class.

Answer (score 0):

**By using (serialize and deserialize) you can do that.**

Serialize the object at client side(it will sending as byte of array).

Deserialize the received byte of array to your object at web service side.

Use the below code:

```
    // Convert an object to a byte array
    private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
       if(obj == null)
       return null;
       BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
       return ms.ToArray();
    }

    // Convert a byte array to an Object
    private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
      MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
      BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
      memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
      memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      Object obj = (Object) binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
      return obj;
    }
```